# Converting "January 5th" and "February 1st" to dates (removing ordinals/th/rd/st)

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, format, ordinal

I have ~100 rows of live data from a website that look like this:

> January 24th 12:30pm NINJA Party
>
> January 31st 3:30pm Classic Party

How can I get Google Sheets to recognize the dates? It doesn't recognize the ordinal endings (e.g. th/st/rd).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This formula might work as you want (amend the A2:A range as required):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:A,SEARCH(" ",A2:A)+2)),DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:A,SEARCH(" ",A2:A)+1))))))`